# Issue re-using XAML paths for use within Windows 8 Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to re-use a XAML `<Path />` that I have made for an icon in my Windows 8 Store App, however when I attempt to re-use them more than once, it never displays?

For example, both the initial instances are fine and my Tick/Cross path renders with this XAML code:

```
<Path x:Name="TickGlyph" Style="{StaticResource TickGlyph}" Fill="#FF008500"
  Grid.Column="1" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="24,0,4,0" />
<Path x:Name="CrossGlyph" Style="{StaticResource CrossGlyph}" Fill="#FF850000"
  Grid.Column="1" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="24,0,4,0" />
```

As soon as I repeat that code with names like `TickGlyph1` etc, my subsequent paths are simply blank, could anybody explain what's going on here, or is this some weird limitation with XAML for Windows Store apps?

My underlying Styles are as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="TickGlyph" TargetType="Path">
  <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 45.12,5.49L 21.255,40.8L 20.4525,40.8L 0,23.2875L 5.775,15.7875L 19.2525,27.3L 37.695,-1.90735e-006L 45.12,5.49 Z "/>
  <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CrossGlyph" TargetType="Path">
  <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 0,32.505L 13.4025,19.1025L 0,5.69249L 5.67,-7.62939e-006L 19.08,13.41L 32.505,-7.62939e-006L 38.205,5.67L 24.7725,19.1025L 38.205,32.535L 32.505,38.205L 19.08,24.795L 5.67,38.205L 0,32.505 Z "/>
  <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"></Setter>
</Style>
```

---

**Update 2012-10-20:** 
The strange thing is, if I replace `Style="{StaticResource TickGlyph}"` for `Data="F1 M 45.12,5.49L 21.255,40.8L 20.4525,40.8L 0,23.2875L 5.775,15.7875L 19.2525,27.3L 37.695,-1.90735e-006L 45.12,5.49 Z "` all my paths load ok, why won't the `Style` attribute honour? :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: No sorry devson, for now I duplicated each `<Path />`. I don't particularly like the idea of making a new .xaml file for each path as per Martin's solution, but it may work if you want to give it a try.

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up wrapping the Path in a ContentControl like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8838443/25182

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if it's the best solution, but I have used this approach few days ago:

Define your own object that inherits from Path using XAML

```xml
<Path x:Class="MyProject.MyPath"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Data="F1M1568.35,1934.42L1551.46,1917.44 1551.46,1925.43C1517.67,1925.43 1515.02,1945.4 1515.02,
        1949.39 1522.31,1933.42 1551.46,1941.4 1551.46,1941.4L1551.46,1949.39 1568.35,1934.42z"
    Stretch="Uniform" Width="26" Height="26" UseLayoutRounding="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
</Path>
```

use default codebehind

```cs
public partial class MyPath 
{
    public MyPath()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and then instantiate it where you want.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, did you resort to this because you also had trouble doing it the way I did Martin?

Comment: I was trying to solve another issue in WP7 app - if you use Icon somewhere, you need to have one for black and one for white theme. I rather wanted to use one object with color defined using Style - this worked.

Comment: Ah okay. Actually for a WP7 app I did, mine automatically changed accordingly depending on color theme on phone? (For app bar that is)

Comment: AppBar buttons are changing the color automatically, but you have to provide right image/element for other visual elements or buttons.